# How to Highlight a entire recycler view row, when a button inside that row is clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to highlight that recycler view row , when the button inside that row and is clicked , Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each adapter has a view called `itemView` which represents whole row.

So, in your adapter's onBindViewHolder, set onClickListener like that(I use lambda, but you can replace it with anonymous class):

```
btn.setOnClickListener(view -> itemView.setBackground(....))
```